# Percentual padding top causes white gap on bottom

Tags: css

I want to create a slope shape on top of my div. The solution consists of main div (with content) and top tiv (triangle shape). For top div i have specified a correct background, clip-path property, and percentual padding top (for fixed ratio on diferent widths). Problem is percentual padding when resulting height of shape in pixel has decimals. The shape has extra white space on bottom. How to eliminate/fill this white space ?

[image]

triangle div css props

```
background: gray;
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
padding-top: 15%;
margin-bottom: 0;
```

I am not looking for workarounds. I want to keep both elements and specifying clip-path on rectangle element wont work for me. I am looking for answers how to round the final height after percentage calculation.

reproduction https://jsfiddle.net/vt5pr6a1/6/
Resize result to see problem

Comment: Could you provide us with CSS and HTML code?

Comment: @AnthonyBeaumecker I think it is not necessary provided info should be enough to reproduce this problem. Added triangle styles anyway.

Comment: are there any margin or padding on the footer?

Comment: The provided code might be the core of the problem, but without seeing a complete reproducing example, any answer has to make assumptions about your issue, which leads to bad answers. Please include the markup, CSS selector, and any other CSS required to cause the issue.

Comment: code available in question

Comment: @ErikParso Would it be acceptable for you to apply the clipping on the parent and still having 2 child elements? Because it would work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it only one element

```css
.footer {
  background: gray;
  /*                         v-- added an extra point using 15%xsreen width */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 15vw, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  padding-top: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

body  {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  foter content<br>
  here
</div>
```

Comment: Id like to keep current html structure. This question is more oriented to find solution how to round this percentage calculation. Ill add it in question.

Comment: @ErikParso you didn't provide any html structure ...

Comment: well i said it consists of 2 elements, ...updated question with more specification

Comment: @ErikParso saying *2 elements* is not enough. Nested element? not nested? what type of element? etc

Comment: 2 sibling elements in one parent container, i think it is enough, important is triangle shape which gains extra white space on bottom

Comment: @ErikParso why not sharing a full working code? it would be easier for everyone. Describing code is not usefull. We have to see the code

Comment: @ErikParso apply my code to the parent element: https://jsfiddle.net/og3qha1p/ and it's done (no HTML changed and same structure kept)

Comment: Again. I am not searching for workarounds. This clip path has to be set on triangle component. I receive this component with clip-path already defined and i cannot override it in my app by static. The proportions of triangle can be changed any time.

Comment: @ErikParso I not providing *workarounds*, I am providing solutions ;) .. If you want to fix your issue you need to *change* something. If you cannot change anything, I don't see how you can fix your issue.

Comment: @ErikParso This is getting pathetic really. He (Termani Afif) is right. If you cannot fix it easily you have to find a solution somehow. The straightforward solution is always "the solution" and the others are "workarounds" you have to deal with it. Nothing is just perfect. Sometimes bugs occur and you have to fix it somehow - rounding errors are just that. Sometimes it is also a question of X/Y.

Comment: This is solution that might help somebody else but not me. We can close this one

Comment: @ErikParso no need to close anything. You are not obliged to accept this solution and you can wait for more but add all the details your provided here to your question so people trying to give a solution should know **all** the restrictions you listed here (even if they are overkill restrictions)